# post hasmany photo and i want insert post_id

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

this is the controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = new Post;
    $photo = new Photo;
    $user = Auth::user();
    $input = $request->except('file');
    $input['user_id'] =$user->id;
    $post->create($input);
    if ($files = $request->file('file')) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = $photo->create(['file'=>$name, $photo->post_id => $post->id]); 
    }
}
return 'Upload successful!';
```

and this is the model

```
protected $fillable = ['file', 'post_id', 'user_id'];
protected $uploads = '/images/';

public function post() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}


public function getFileAttribute($photo) {  
    return $this->uploads . $photo;  
}
```

i get this error 
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into photos (file, post_id, updated_at, created_at

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```php
$photo = $photo->create(['file'=>$name, 'post_id' => $post->id]);
```